# Get Author Count By Day, Week and Month

Tags: author, date, count

I have a standard loop and I want to by the author's name show how many posts were published for the current day by an author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not where I can run the below, but potential typos, etc. aside, it should be able to point you in the right direction.

### 1) Limit Query

You could add [Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to your query arguments to limit them.

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->posts;
```

---

### 2) Build `author_id => post count` array

Then get all the author ids as array keys to force unique entries, and count as value:

```
$authors = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
   if ( array_key_exists( $post->post_author ) {
        $authors[$post->post_author] = ++$authors[$post->post_author];
   }
   else {
        $authors[$post->post_author] = 1; 
   } 
}
```

---

### 3) echo author name and count

Then loop through that array to get the values:

```
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {

   // since the key is the numeric id, we will use it to get display name
   echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', key($author) ) .': '. $author;
}
```

Comment: I think you have my question wrong. I am trying to get the users published post count. (ex. Tracy Woods - 10 Posts Today, Nicholas Walker - 3 Posts This Week)

Comment: Sorry, I was going off of _The function below only gives you all of the authors posts, but I just only want to display post(s) for the current day._

Comment: Since you have rephrased this question elsewhere and received a rather complete answer over there, I would just delete this question so it doesn't hang around unanswered. birgire's answer seems rather complete.

Comment: I can rephrase this question to fit your answer and mark complete instead of deleting in case someone is looking for your answer.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right on that. Cool. :)